# How to access JDBC driver which configured as JNDI resource, from Spring?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, datasource, jndi

My application is based of Spring MVC template.

I have configured my `DataSource` with the following tag in my context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/registrator" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="javauser" password="javauser" driverClassName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrator"/>
```

Am I right thinking this will cause Tomcat to create a server-wide instance of `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` bean and make it available under "jdbc/registrator" name?

Should I also describe this resource in `web.xml` as told here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources? Probably this is not required if I use Spring framework?

How can I access this bean from Spring context configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `jee` namespace for this (see [C.2.3 The jee schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee)):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/registrator"/>
```

That defines a bean called `dataSource` that represents your Tomcat datasource.

No need to add anything to `web.xml`.